# beautifulsoup - scraping an item through class with condition

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

for example I have this html

```
<div class="item-1">a</div>
<div class="item-3">b</div>
<div class="item-6">c</div>
<div class="item-8">aaaaaa</div>
...... item-x keep increasing randomly on it class
<div class="item-100">aaaaaa</div>
```

I want to scrap all of the class item-X where the value of X is between 5 to 10

I know how to search with a partial class name

```
text = soup.select('div[class*="item-"]')
```

but I don't know how to add conditions for it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use for loop.

```
import bs4 as bs

html = """
<div class="item-1">a</div>
<div class="item-3">b</div>
<div class="item-6">c</div>
<div class="item-8">aaaaaa</div>
<div class="item-100">aaaaaa</div>
"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for i in range(5, 10):
    text = soup.select('div[class*="item-' + str(i) + '"]')
    if text:
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple CSS selectors joined by `,`:

```py
html_doc = """\
<div class="item-1">a</div>
<div class="item-3">b</div>
<div class="item-6">c</div>
<div class="item-8">aaaaaa</div>
<div class="item-100">aaaaaa</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

texts = soup.select(",".join(f"div.item-{i}" for i in range(5, 11)))
for text in texts:
    print(text)
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="item-6">c</div>
<div class="item-8">aaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: I tried using this but with <a> HTML tag., it gives me an empty list 

`texts = soup.select(",".join(f"a.item-{i}" for i in range(5, 11)))`
 
(assuming the html tag there is <a> instead of <div>

Comment: @Gagak Make sure the `<a>` tag is there. Try `print(soup)` before selecting the tags and inspect the source.

Comment: I tried using `text = soup.select('a[class*="item-"]')` it works fine

Comment: @Gagak without seeing the source it's hard to tell. Are you sure the class is just `item-1` and not `some_string_item-1_some_string` ?

Comment: the actual class name is `js-board__title board-link board-1`

Comment: @Gagak So try `texts = soup.select(",".join(f"a.board-{i}" for i in range(5, 11)))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245547/discussion-between-gagak-and-andrej-kesely).